# Python 2.7.13 - print command issue

Tags: python, input

I am absolutely new to python programming. i have written the below piece of code:

```
'''Lets us just learn python'''

print ("Hey God Help Me !!!")
name = raw_input("Enter Name:")
print name
```

While i run the code it asks for the input as intended however it doesn't print anything and looks like going in a infinite loop. i have used the same code in [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python) system and it works. can someone help me understand what may be the issue?

i have tried using other functions and it works. Even tried manually entering the value in the code and that too works. However when ever i try to take a input from the user, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you actually press Enter after entering `name`?

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin dude.. hes using 3+ and 2.7 syntax lol... all good.. again, we gota get you some good tutorials... I got a sh!t to of ebooks, willing , entired course thought... up to him and how much he wants toput in

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin: i did, but it seems to get stuck in a loop and does not do anything. So i did couple of other steps but the problem seemed to persist.I even changed the editor from Sublime 3 to sublime 2 and then to Atom but no help. i am currently learning from Codeacademy, I requested their help and they also said there is no problem with the code.And they suggested i try Pycharm for the text editor - And guess what : It worked .i am very new to Python and my knowledge for detecting the source of problem is very limited so i believe i can blame it on the editor and stay happy.

Comment: So it was the editor making everything so complicated. You can avoid such problems by launching Python in a command line.

Comment: Actually, editors like Sublime Text and Atom are intended to _edit_ text, including program source code, not executing it. So there is no big surprise that they don't handle text user input properly when executing a Python script. PyCharm is an IDE, intended to make programs with Python, so it works. But it still doesn't handle some cmd line features like screen clearing (my own experience), so command line is practically irreplaceable

Comment: for python 2 & 3 compatible code, add this line `from __future__ import print_function` then always using `print(name)` and never `print name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after you changed your problem description to one, that I recommended initially:

```
print ("Hey God Help Me !!!") 
name = raw_input("Enter Name:") 
print name
```

then you need to assure you're using python 2.7 for 2 options of print statement -
 `print name` and `print(name)` - to work.

Just in case you're using python 3x, please modify `print name` to `print(name)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello fri3nd!

Welcome to party, I envy you! Not that I feel I've reached any plateau but that's the nature of the IT sector... You stay compliant to the current standard or your behind you... Anyhow firstly..

1. You say your on python 2.7?  Youll quickly learn that firstly I assure you is that in 2.7 and 3.0+ you have different method of having to write your actual code... and the first ever code will have a printt lets take that for example...

#### Python 2.7

> print 'HEY TH3R3'

#### Python3.0+

> print('SEE THE DIFFERENCE?')

So when your running the code you provided... your mixing and matching which ... just cant be done,... So what your code would turnout to be properly

### Python3.0+

```
name = input("gHey its... not god lol... whats your name? \n:")
greeting = "Oh! hi {}".format(name)
print(greeting)
```

I wont toch the 2.7 syntax but aside from the fact that we need to get you some quality tutorials lol... whats more important here is thatyou get the :logic of the language build... So much awesomeness awaits you.  You ever need some help drop me a message but you have to put in that effort son lol.. but Ill give you a pass and place most of the blame oh bad source for the beging of the trip but yeah... google is your friend

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation... i tried all the changes suggested however for the time being it looked like something to do with the editor as the command with corrections as suggested worked on Pycharm. I am currently learning python from Codeacademy but i will be more than happy to get any good suggestions from your side. I am learning Python for BigData. Can you suggest shall i learn python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Again... you should concentrate on 3.5+ but should be of some of the differences in syntax ... theres still a lot of 2.7 based applications out there due to... well theres manyreasons bute yea ... OH! Take it from me ... you should REALLY consider using your codingprojectsin a virtua enviroment.... just google it... but please please read over these links https://pythontips.com/2013/07/30/what-is-virtualenv/ 
and also
http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/